# Typescript + Redux Toolkit, Argument of type 'T' is not assignable to parameter of type 'WritableDraft<T>'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux-toolkit, immer.js

I am new to Typescript and trying to use Redux-Toolkit with it in my React application. Here I am trying to create a To Do application with a nested state where each `ToDo` contains a array of `Comment`. Here are the interfaces:

`Comment.ts`

```
export interface Comment {
    id: number;
    comment: string;
}
```

`ToDo.ts`

```
export interface ToDo {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    description: string;
    comments: Array<Comment>;
}
```

Then in my `ToDoSlice`:

```
export const toDoSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'toDoSlice',
    initialState: [] as Array<ToDo>,
    reducers: {
        addToDo: (state, action: PayloadAction<ToDo> ) => {
            state.push(action.payload);
        },
    }
});
```

The TS compiler throws this on the line `state.push(action.payload)`:

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'ToDo' is not assignable to parameter of type 'WritableDraft<ToDo>'.
  Types of property 'comments' are incompatible.
    Type 'Comment[]' is not assignable to type 'WritableDraft<Comment>[]'.
      Type 'Comment' is not assignable to type 'WritableDraft<Comment>'.
        The types of 'ownerDocument.all' are incompatible between these types.
          Type 'HTMLAllCollection' is not assignable to type 'WritableDraft<HTMLAllCollection>'.
            'number' index signatures are incompatible.
              Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'WritableDraft<Element>'.
                Types of property 'attributes' are incompatible.
                  Type 'NamedNodeMap' is not assignable to type 'WritableDraft<NamedNodeMap>'.
                    'number' index signatures are incompatible.
                      Type 'Attr' is not assignable to type 'WritableDraft<Attr>'.
                        Types of property 'childNodes' are incompatible.
                          Type 'NodeListOf<ChildNode>' is not assignable to type 'WritableDraft<NodeListOf<ChildNode>>'.
                            'number' index signatures are incompatible.
                              Type 'ChildNode' is not assignable to type 'WritableDraft<ChildNode>'.
                                Types of property 'parentElement' are incompatible.
                                  Type 'HTMLElement | null' is not assignable to type 'WritableDraft<HTMLElement> | null'.
                                    Type 'HTMLElement' is not assignable to type 'WritableDraft<HTMLElement>'.
                                      Types of property 'shadowRoot' are incompatible.
                                        Type 'ShadowRoot | null' is not assignable to type 'WritableDraft<ShadowRoot> | null'.
                                          Type 'ShadowRoot' is not assignable to type 'WritableDraft<ShadowRoot>'.
                                            Types of property 'adoptedStyleSheets' are incompatible.
                                              Type 'CSSStyleSheet[]' is not assignable to type 'WritableDraft<CSSStyleSheet>[]'.
                                                Type 'CSSStyleSheet' is not assignable to type 'WritableDraft<CSSStyleSheet>'.
                                                  Types of property 'ownerNode' are incompatible.
                                                    Type 'Element | ProcessingInstruction | null' is not assignable to type 'WritableDraft<Element> | WritableDraft<ProcessingInstruction> | null'.
                                                      Type 'ProcessingInstruction' is not assignable to type 'WritableDraft<Element> | WritableDraft<ProcessingInstruction> | null'.
```

---

I tried to cast the `action.payload` to type `WritableDraft<ToDo>`, and the error does go away.

```
addToDo: (state, action: PayloadAction<ToDo> ) => 
    {state.push(action.payload as WritableDraft<ToDo>);
},
```

However, similar problem arises when I try to add a `Comment` into an existing `ToDo`:

```
addComment: (state, action: PayloadAction<{toDoId: number, comment: Comment}>) => {
    const toDo = state.find(toDo => toDo.id === action.payload.toDoId);
            
    if (toDo) {
        toDo.comments.push(action.payload.comment);
    }
}
```

where it gives another error:

```
Argument of type 'Comment' is not assignable to parameter of type 'WritableDraft<Comment>'.
  Type 'Comment' is missing the following properties from type 'WritableDraft<Comment>': data, length, ownerDocument, appendData, and 59 more.
```

and casting `action.payload.comment as WritableDraft<Comment>` won't do. The error almost remains the same.

---

The version of the dependencies inside of the `package.json`:

```json
"dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.2.1",
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.1",
    "@types/node": "^16.7.13",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.4.3",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.4.2",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.0"
  },
```

Comment: I run your code and i do not see any typescript error. i tested your code using react v17.0.2 and redux-toolkit v1.5.1. Can you specify the redux-toolkit and react version? I'm not sure but may be typescript throw this error when you try to dispatch with incorrect payload. 
Also WritableDraft type is incorrect to use here. `state` inside the reducer function is `Draft`.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I have now edited the post to show the versions inside of `package.json`. Typescript reported this error on the line `state.push(action.payload)`, when I haven't written any dispatching logic yet

Comment: After using your package.json, I still do not see any typescript error. Can you create minimal working example using sandbox like codesandbox.io so it's easy to identify the issue in your code?

Comment: Sure. Here's the codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-bouman-5q2qm2. If you open `toDoSlice.ts` in `src/redux` directory, you can see the red squiggly line at line 14 and 25. Strangely enough the application runs fine at codesandbox but not in my local machine, I think maybe the codesandbox doesn't strictly check for Typescript because if I change `state.toDoList.push(action.payload);` to something like `state.toDoList.push(action.payload.notexist)`, the application still runs fine (although with squiggly lines telling the error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `ToDo.ts` file inside `models` folder, you just need to import `Comment` interface from `Comment.ts`.

```
import { Comment } from './Comment'
```

This will fix that typescript error.

Comment: Oh my god, thank you so much. Can't really believe the entire problem is due to the type collision of the `Comment`!

Answer (score 1):

you should write this:

```
reducers: {
    addToDo: (state, action: PayloadAction<ToDo> ) => {
        state.push(action.payload as ToDo);
    },
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, unfortunately, that does not make the issue go away. It still reports the same error as if I have written `state.push(action.payload)`